# SQL to analyze data after migration

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a lot of data migrated and now wants to check them for correctness.

Below is a simple example:
I have migrated a table which was already filled in another.
Now I want to check the number of both tables and compare.
In addition I have created the following query:

```
SELECT 'Prüfung1' AS "Prüfung", (CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM TableA) = (SELECT count(*) FROM TableB)
    THEN 'OK!' 
    ELSE '!!! Anzahl stimmt nicht überein !!!' END) "Ergebnis" FROM dual
```

However, I would carry out several such tests, and show as one result. If I will be replacements in a second test this appears as a column rather than a row.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'Prüfung1' AS "Prüfung", (CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM TableA) = (SELECT count(*) FROM TableB)
    THEN 'OK!' 
    ELSE '!!! Anzahl stimmt nicht überein !!!' END) "Ergebnis" FROM dual) check1,
    (
    SELECT 'Prüfung2' AS "Prüfung", (CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM TableC) = (SELECT count(*) FROM TableD)
    THEN 'OK!' 
    ELSE '!!! Anzahl stimmt nicht überein !!!' END) "Ergebnis" FROM dual) check2;
```

My Result should be:

```
|Tests|Result|
|Check1|Result1|
|Check2|Result2|
|Check3|Result3|
...
```

How can I do that best?

Sorry for my englsih! ;-)

**Update for @vercelli**

Here the query with the ORA-00904 Error:

```
with myTables as (select 'tableA' as tableName, count(*) as howMany from MIGRATION_OLDTABLE1 union all
              select 'tableB' as tableName, count(*) as howMany from OLDTABLE1 union all
              select 'tableC' as tableName, count(*) as howMany from MIGRATION_OLDTABLE2 union all
              select 'tableD' as tableName, count(*) as howMany from OLDTABLE2
              --....
              --select 'tableN' as tableName, count(*) from TableC
              ),
myRelations (select 'tableA' as newTable, 'tableB' as oldtable from dual union all
             select 'tableC' as newTable, 'tableD' as oldtable from dual )
select DECODE(a1.howMany, a2.howMany, 'OK', 'KO') as results , r.newTable ||' : ' || to_char(a1.howMany) ||' vs. '|| r.oldTable || ' : ' || to_char(a2.howMany) diff
from myTables a1 join myRelations r on a1.tableName = r.newTable
               join myTables a2 on a2.tableName = r.oldTable;
```

Comment: I am not sure what you really want as a result. Just the tables where the rowcounts are different? Or the rows that have different values? Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a subquery with the `count(*)` of all the tables with their `tableName`.
Another subquery with all the relations (`newTable` vs. `oldTable`)
Then join them and compare the `count(*)`.

```
with myTables as (select 'tableA' as tableName, count(*) as howMany from tableA union all
                  select 'tableB' as tableName, count(*) as howMany from tableB union all
                  ....
                  select 'tableN' as tableName, count(*) from tableN),
    myRelations as (select 'tableA' as newTable, 'tableB' as oldtable from dual union all
                 select 'tableC' as newTable, 'tableD' as oldtable from dual )
select DECODE(a1.howMany, a2.howMany, 'OK', 'KO') as results , r.newTable ||' : ' || to_char(a1.howMany) ||' vs. '|| r.oldTable || ' : ' || to_char(a2.howMany) diff
  from myTables a1 join myRelations r on a1.tableName = r.newTable
                   join myTables a2 on a2.tableName = r.oldTable
  ;
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
results diff
  KO    tableA : 5624 vs. tableB: 5476
  OK    tableC : 1576 vs. tableD: 1576
```

Comment: I got a ORA-00904 Error!

Comment: Invalid identifier? Please post your query.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstand tableN. Where put i Table C and D?

Comment: Is it correct that after tableN there is no union all?

Comment: Yes, since is the last one.

Comment: Where can i post the query? Answer my question or edit my post?

Comment: @MartinSchlesier edit your post, you can give it format.

Comment: @MartinSchlesier got it, missing `as` after myRelations. I fixed it

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I will test it with more tables other conditions.

Comment: @MartinSchlesier great! This is pretty flexible, you could compare a table with many others (not just one). You could also create a new condition like max(), min(), count(distinct ), avg()

Comment: Is it possible to use different conditions for example: row 1-4 howMany, row 5-8 max, ...

Comment: @MartinSchlesier If you are comparing 2 tables by 2 different criteria, it's better if the results are on the same row in different columns. If you want them on different rows, do an `union all` of the last query comparing by the new criteria

Comment: No, i have an other table where i want to count() but with a where condition. I add a select with a where condition in myTables and another select in myrelations. Why is the last select in the first row of the result? What is the order condition here?

Comment: @MartinSchlesier Yes, add the select on myTables and it's relations on myRelations. You may add a new column as number on myRelations queries to order by it

Comment: I add a number for every select in myRelations but it don´t work with "order by relation.checkOrder"! TO_NUMBER() also, strange!

Comment: Order by r.checkOrder (the alias is r)

Comment: I changed it to "relation" ;-)

Comment: @MartinSchlesier Then, i don't get the error. Post your new query.

Comment: Sorry had an semicolon before the order by! Sorry my mistake, now it works great!